# Vue JS - Mutating Passed Props in Slot

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I know that it is bad to mutate props in Vue, however, I'm not sure if this applies when you passed a prop via a slot.
I have the following parent component with a slot inside.

Parent Component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    ..
    <slot :form="form"></slot>
    ..
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'parent-component',
  data () {
    return {
      form: new Form({
        fieldForParent: '',
        fieldForChild: '',
      })
    }
}
</script>
```

ChildComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <parent-component>
    <template v-slot = "{form}">
      <input v-model="form.fieldForChild" />
    </template>
  </parent-component>
</template>
```

The real confusion here to me is which one should be considered the parent and a child. Basically, ChildComponent.vue is the one composing the parent component but it also nests its value inside the parent element. Moreover, data from API is being fetched from the parent component.

Here's my question:
Is this the correct way of doing it? I'm doing it for reusability since there will be multiple instances of the child component that will have common fields (hence the parent component) but there will also be fields that are unique for each child. Note that after mutating the props inside the child component (by updating the input element), I am not getting the "Avoid mutating a prop directly .." warning.

Comment: scoped slots are used to expose some data to the parent component from the child one

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim does this mean that it is okay to mutate that data in the slot?

Comment: you're reversing the logic the first component should be child and the second one should be parent